# Having trouble to set up SSH socks proxy

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel, socks

I am trying to set up a SSH socks tunnel for my personal use. When I am using this command `ssh -D 1080 -N root@[server public IP]` to start the proxy I am getting this error: `open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed`. Please help me.

**Server SSHD Config:**

```
tcpkeepalive yes
allowtcpforwarding yes
permitopen any
```

**Server Info:** CentOS 7

Comment: `administratively prohibited` seems pretty clear: you're not allowed to do that.